# Open an excel file in exclusive mode using interop in C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

In my application I want to be able to open an excel file that already exists, and add information to this file. I use the Microsoft Interop libraries. I have noticed that if you create a new spreadsheet using Add and then Saveas you can set the file to be in exclusive mode until you close the excel application.

However I haven't found a way to do the same when Opening an existing file. The reason I want to do that is because, if I open the excel file while my application is open, then I get an exception. I presume that when I am opening the excel file using excel, it is automatically opened in exclusive mode.

I though of opening the file and then using saveas, but it didn't work.

```
private object missing=Type.Missing;
workbook = workbooks.Open(excelfilename,missing, false, missing, missing, missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,false, missing,missing, missing, missing);
workbook.SaveAs((String)excelfilename, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, missing, missing, missing, missing);
```

I am getting the exception later in the code:

```
Excel.Range testrange = sheet.get_Range(rangetext);
```

The exception I am getting is a COMException, "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401A8".

Comment: You already have exclusive access when opening an existing file, you'd have to use ReadOnly to allow sharing.  The exception has little to do with this.  Take the last 4 hex digits and convert them to decimal, then google it by putting "Excel error" in front of it.  Plenty of hits.

Comment: Even if this is the case, when I open the file with excel while the application is running it doesn't notify me that it can be done in read only mode. When I create my own spreadsheet and use saveas, then I don't have the problem, and Excel can only open the file in read only mode.

Comment: Are you using two different `Excel.Application` instances, or just one?

Comment: I am using one instance. But I would like to make sure that if I open that file using excel, I won't have errors as the above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Workbook class ExclusiveAccess property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.exclusiveaccess(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I have tried adding the ExclusiveAccess() method after I use Open and even after I use SaveAs, but this doesn't seek to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to [this article](http://technico.qnownow.com/2012/03/22/how-to-automate-excel-in-c/) for complete example of how to open an excel file/ add new sheet/ get range & set properties
using Microsoft interop library